# Text in Blender won't render

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

So, I just started using Blender about a week or so ago, so forgive me if the answer to this is literally right in front of me.

But I was editing a channel banner for one of my friends and added text behind it:
[image]

But.. As you can see here, when I go to render it the text doesn't show up.
[image]

At first I thought it was just because the background was transparent or something, but that didn't seem to be the case. How do I fix this?

EDIT: Here are the material settings

[image]
[image]

Comment: What are the material settings for the text? Please [edit] your question and add more information.

Comment: Or post .blend file here: blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: Alright, i added in the material settings

Comment: I don't know how exactly it should look but you can change 'Volume' to 'Surface' in Material Tab.

Comment: Oh.
Oh my God I'm so dumb

Comment: Keep learning and have a great time with Blender ;)

Comment: @LukeD can you write an answer? Let's move this one out of the unanswered questions list : )

Comment: @cegaton Thanks, I'm still new here and I always think that right answer in comments is enough ;)

Answer (score 1):

In *Material Tab* change *Volume* to *Surface*.